# How to disable redundant path warning for a d2600 with 12 HP SATA drives?

Tags: sas, sata, redundancy, raid-controller, hpe

Have a HP p822 RAID controller with FirmWare 8.32 cabled to a HPE **d2600** with 12 x 4TB **SATA** drives in RAID60.  These are not dual-port SAS drives, but 4TB SATA drives so there is only one pathway to each drive.  With either one or two miniSAS cables, there is a redundancy warning:

"**799  Logical Drive 7 is degraded due to the loss of a redundant path.**"

How can i disable this warning such that the amber warning light is not "Crying Wolf?"

SATA Drives are HP ATA MB4000ECWLR with firmware HPG4.

Turns out pressing F2 to disable the warning at boot-up does in fact work, but is there a better way, preferably in the HP Smart Storage Administrator or hpssacucli?

Answer (score 0):

f2 on the BIOS bootup screen did in fact work, i thought i had tried that before, but probably did not have the iLO window in focus.  Hoping this does not hide real warnings in the future about actual broken redundant paths.

Comment: If there is a better way, would like to know.

Comment: Did you buy the exact compatible disk type? They might have redundant paths using trays with interposer adapters for the single SATA port

Comment: @Zac67, this particular d2600 came with these HPE branded SATA harddrives and these exact same drives have been in use for more than a year.  The warning happened after the firmware on the p822 was updated from 8.0.0 to 8.32.0.   All of the drives appear green.  HPSSA recognizes them as SATA drives, but will  pull a drive caddy during downtime to see if there is an interposer card.

Comment: Apparently, the firmware logic has changed somewhat. You might want to contact HPE support on this, but it's quite possible that this change is intentional. Any mention in the release notes?